# creating new canvas animations on click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am a beginner in canvas and I got stuck in creating multiple images in canvas. I created a ball which bounces inside canvas. Now I want to create a second ball when I click somewhere in the canvas. If my question is too dump please spare me. Here is the code.

The animate function gets executed onpage load:

```
function animate()
{
    // do something
    setInterval(function(){drawBall(ball_props,color,null);},10);
}

function drawBall(ball_props,color)
{
    var c = document.getElementById("bouncy_ball");
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

    trajactory(ball_props);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball_props.center_x,ball_props.center_y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = "2";
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();

    boundaryConditions(ball_props);

    accelerator(ball_props);
};
```

This helped me in creating the first ball in my canvas animation. Now i have a click function which is supposed to trigger the second ball but instead its deleting the first ball and creating a new one.

```
function onclickingCanvas()
{
    setInterval(function(){drawBall(ball2_props,color2);},10);
}
```

Could you please help me fix this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing really changes by just calling your setInterval again in your click function, because you just "overwriting" it. you have to call the drawBall function twice (one time for the first ball, a second time for the second ball). Hope that helps.

Comment: calling the function alone wont help me. I need setInterval to make the ball move. If there is any alternative could you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line means that you clear your canvas each time you call "drawball" function :

```
context.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
```

So if you want to draw a second ball, you should call "drawball" once but with an array containing all the balls... something like that :

```
var ball1 = {
    ball_props: ball_props,
    color: color
}, ball2 = {
    ball_props: ball2_props,
    color: color2
};

var balls = [ball1];


function animate(){
    setInterval(function(){drawBall(balls);},10);
}

function drawBall(balls)
{
    var c = document.getElementById("bouncy_ball");
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

    for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++){

        trajactory(balls[i].ball_props);

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(balls[i].ball_props.center_x,balls[i].ball_props.center_y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = balls[i].color;
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = "2";
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.stroke();

        boundaryConditions(balls[i].ball_props);

        accelerator(balls[i].ball_props);
    }

};


function onclickingCanvas(){
    balls.push(ball2);
}
```

Haven't tested it... but well you have the idea now.